# Can a partially tail-recursive function still gain the optimization advantages of a fully tail-recursive function?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, partial, tail-recursion

I realise the answer to this question could be different for different languages, and the language I am most interested in is C++. If the tag needs be changed because this can't be answered in a language-agnostic manner, feel free.

---

Is it possible to have a function be partially tail-recursive and still get any advantage that being tail-recursive would get you?

As I understand it, tail-recursion is where instead of doing a full function call, the compiler will optimise the function to just change the arguments in place to the new arguments and jump to the beginning of the function.

If you have a function like this:

```
def example(arg):
    if arg == 0:
        return 0 # base case

    if arg % 2 == 0:
        return example(arg - 1) # should be tail recursive

    return 3 + example(arg - 1) # isn't tail recursive because 3 is added to the result
```

When an optimiser encounters something like that (where the function is tail-recursive in some cases and not in others) will it turn the one into a `jump` and the other into a `call`, or will some fact of optimisation reality (if I knew it I wouldn't be asking) make it have to turn everything into a `call` and lose all the efficiency you would have had if the function were tail-recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, the first language that comes to mind when I think of tail calls, the second case is guaranteed to be a tail call by the language specification.  (Terminology note: it is preferred to refer to such function calls as 'tail calls'.)

The Scheme specification defines exactly what tail calls are in Scheme and mandates that compilers support them specially.  You can see the definition in *11.20. Tail calls and tail contexts* of R<sup>6</sup>RS ([source](http://www.r6rs.org/)).

Note that in Scheme, the specification says nothing about optimization of tail calls.  Rather, it says that an implementation must support an unbounded number of active tail calls — a semantic property of the language runtime.  They can be implemented as normal calls, but usually aren't.

**Example, in C:**

Take a C version of your example.

```
int example(int arg)
{
    if (arg == 0)
        return 0;
    if ((arg % 2) == 0)
        return example(arg - 1);
    return 3 + example(arg - 1);
}
```

Compile it using gcc's usual optimization settings (`-O2`) for i386:

```
_example:
    pushl   %ebp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    testl   %edx, %edx
    jne L5
    jmp L15
    .align 4,0x90
L14:
    decl    %edx
    testl   %edx, %edx
    je  L7
L5:
    testb   $1, %dl
    je  L14
    decl    %edx
    addl    $3, %eax
    testl   %edx, %edx
    jne L5
L7:
    leave
    ret
L15:
    leave
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Note that there are no function calls in the assembly code.  GCC has not only optimized your tail call into a jump, it optimized the non-tail call into a jump as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, a smart compiler could apply tail recursion to your first call by just jumping to the example entry point instead of setting up a new stack frame. A following return will unwind the stack to the original caller, effectively "ending" both calls in one step, even if it cannot do that for the other call.

And you could optimize your function by moving the adding of 3 inside the call:

```
def example(arg, add=0):
    arg += add
    ....
    return example(arg - 1, 3)  # tail now too
```

Another technique would be to create a second function and have both call each other.

I don't know if python or C++ compilers can handle that though, but you can check assembly output for C++. Strangely I think checking bytecode output for python may be harder.

Comment: Yeah I know I can change it where it's unconditionally tail recursive but I wanted to give an example of what I was talking about. And yes, I'm pretty sure that C++ (at least MSVC++) can turn mutually recursive functions into tail-calls.

Comment: The CPython implementation *never* optimizes tail calls, and Guido has put his foot down on the subject, calling it "unpythonic".  See http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html

Comment: @Dietrich yeah, I noticed this when I tried what should have been a tail-recursive factorial function :) too bad guido is so short sighted.

Comment: @Seth: Please don't talk so rudely of language designers.  Tail call optimization comes with trade-offs, it is not an obvious choice.